# Angular, Sequelize, Nodejs updating relational models

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js, mean-stack

I am wondering how to update an associated model using node.js and sequelize.

I'm trying to update the joint (BelongsTo) Category Table.

Review.belongsTo(models.Category, {foreignkey : 'CategoryId', constraints: false});

```
/**  * Update a review  */ exports.update = function(req, res) {

    // create a new variable to hold the review that was placed on the req object.
    var review = req.review;

    review.updateAttributes({
        reviewed                    : req.body.reviewed,
        Category.metaTitle          : req.body.Category.metaTitle
    }).then(function(a){
        return res.jsonp(a);
    }).catch(function(err){
        return res.render('error', {
            error: err,
            status: 500
        });
    }); };
```

Comment: It doesnt accept this line Category.metaTitle          : req.body.Category.metaTitle in the update statement, it crashes the app.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 Category.metaTitle          : req.body.Category.metaTitle to
Category : req.body.Category.metaTitle
```